# convert js function to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am looking at converting compass degrees to a string representing directions. There's another SO post to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490660/converting-wind-direction-in-angles-to-text-words).

This is one answer that modified slightly to represent the complete direction as a word Vs just the abbreviation, would anyone know how to convert this to a Python function? Im looking to have a string returned that represents the 8 cardinal directions... Answer by `Edward Brey Feb 13 '19 at 18:29`

```
function getCardinalDirection(angle) {
    const directions = ['↑ North', '↗ North East', '→ East', '↘ South East', '↓ South', '↙ South West', '← West', '↖ North West'];
    return directions[Math.round(angle / 45) % 8];
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt and what is the problem with that? There is nothing complicated about that function, it should be trivial to write it again in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more straightforward than you think:

```
def getCardinalDirection(angle):
    directions = ['↑ North', '↗ North East', '→ East', '↘ South East', '↓ South', '↙ South West', '← West', '↖ North West']
    return directions[round(angle / 45) % 8]  # round() is a built-in function
```

Example output:

```
>>> getCardinalDirection(50)
'↗ North East'
>>> getCardinalDirection(220)
'↙ South West'
>>> getCardinalDirection(-37)
'↖ North West'
>>> getCardinalDirection(188)
'↓ South'
```

Answer (score 0):

as simple as it is:

```
def get_card_direction(angle):
    directions = ['↑ North', '↗ North East', '→ East', '↘ South East', '↓ South', '↙ South West', '← West', '↖ North West']
    return directions[round(angle/45) % 8]
print(get_card_direction(50)) # output ↗ North East
```